# Disable macros headless libreoffice

Tags: debian, libreoffice

I'm using libreoffice as a pdf converter inside a docker container by utilising the headless functionality. How can I disable macros? I'm using debian strech-9.3 and libreoffice 5.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar manipulating `.idl` files in the LibreOffice source code? According to the documentation you could compile LibreOffice from source and use the value specified [here](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/namespacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1document_1_1MacroExecMode.html#details) to prevent macros. If not you can edit the user profile to prevent macro execution. Here is a [link](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile#GNU.2FLinux).

If those methods do not work you will need to use a different tool to convert files such as [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/).

To utilize pandoc you will need to follow [this post's instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29474929).

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. One question... if I delete the contents of the basic folder in the profile, that means that I effectively disable the macros correct?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the documentation that is one way to disable them. Most people use the menus in the graphical interface but by deleting the folders there shouldn't be a way for macro to run.